# Impossível encontrar componente Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, componentes

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Quero criar uma tela de login e senha. Estou utilizando o primefaces para pegar os componentes, porém não estou conseguindo fazer com que apareça o campo para preencher com a senha.

Analisando com minha visão leiga, parece que ele não reconhece a tag do primefaces

Link do componente no primefaces: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/password.xhtml

index.xhtml:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
 <title>Pagina Incial da Biblioteca</title>
 
</h:head>
<h:body> 

<h:form>
     
    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" />
 
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="matchGrid" cellpadding="5">  
                     
        <h:outputLabel for="pwd1" value="Senha: " />
        <p:password id="pwd1" value="#{passwordView.password5}" match="pwd2" label="Password 1" required="true" />
 
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton update="matchGrid" value="Entrar" />    
</h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

PasswordView:

```java
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class PasswordView {

    private String password1;   
    private String password2;  
    private String password3;  
    private String password4;  
    private String password5;

    public String getPassword1() {
        return password1;
    }

    public void setPassword1(String password1) {
        this.password1 = password1;
    }

    public String getPassword2() {
        return password2;
    }

    public void setPassword2(String password2) {
        this.password2 = password2;
    }

    public String getPassword3() {
        return password3;
    }

    public void setPassword3(String password3) {
        this.password3 = password3;
    }

    public String getPassword4() {
        return password4;
    }

    public void setPassword4(String password4) {
        this.password4 = password4;
    }

    public String getPassword5() {
        return password5;
    }

    public void setPassword5(String password5) {
        this.password5 = password5;
    } 
}
```

Erro apresentado:

> mar 20, 2019 8:58:35 AM com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer getForComponent
>   ADVERTÊNCIA: Não foi possível encontrar o componente com a ID pwd1 na exibição.

[image: Meus Jars]

[image: Resultado]

[image: web.xml]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>2BIIM_Aula9_JSF</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Poderia por gentileza incluir todo o código da sua `index.xhtml`?

Comment: Atualizei, agora com o index.xhtml completo

Comment: Você pode também postar o print da tela que não está abrindo?

Comment: Atualizado, no link do primefaces mostra como deveria ficar.

Link: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/password.xhtml

Comment: você configurou seu `web.xml` mapeando a servlet do JSF? Algo como `javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet`? Caso você não tenha mapeado a extensão `.xhtml` para passar pelo servlet a página não será renderizada de acordo. Por gentileza poste seu `web.xml`

Comment: Atualizado, na imagem 1 e 2 do web.xml existe o javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet, porém não tenho total certeza de que está correto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei o erro, era na configuração do Deployment eu não havia colocado o primefaces lá.

Answer (score 0):

Atualmente o mapeamento do servlet está apenas para urls `/faces/*`

Adicione o seguinte mapeamento ao `web.xml`:

```
<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

Isso irá fazer as páginas `xhtml` serem processadas pelo servlet do JSF.

---

**UPDATE**: Existe mais um detalhe importante em sua implementação, sua versão do **PrimeFaces (3.5)** não suporta o **JSF 2.2**.

Para utilizar JSF 2.2, você deve atualizar o PrimeFaces para no mínimo a **versão 4.0**

Outra opção seria utilizar a **versão 2.1** do JSF.

Mais informações podem ser encontradas [nesta thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832964/primefaces-required-jsf-version) do StackOverflow em inglês

Comment: Ainda está dando o mesmo erro: ADVERTÊNCIA: Não foi possível encontrar o componente com a ID pwd1 na exibição. 
-
-
-
Coloquei o nova mapeamento logo abaixo do /faces/*

Comment: @LucasTrigoSchott complementei a resposta com mais um detalhe

Comment: Cara, atualizei o primefaces para ultima versão, no caso 7.0 e ainda apresenta o erro de impossível encontrar componente

Comment: Deve ser algum erro de configuração do projeto em sí, vou tirar um tempo e subir um projeto de modelo funcionando para você no meu Github, te aviso aqui quando subir lá

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado. Pesquisei outras maneiras de fazer fazer também e estou aqui tentando ;)